# Material UI Tooltip to show content in multi line

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI for the React Components. See the below code and see how I am binding the Tooltip title property.

```
<Tooltip disableFocusListener title={xyzStore.mytestMultiLineContent}   >
    <span>
        <Button color={'primary'}   variant={'contained'}
            onClick={this.handleXYZ}
            disabled={!xyzStore.canSaveXYZ}
        >
            <Icon fontSize={'small'} >{'save'}</Icon>
            <Typography variant={'button'} >{'Save XYZ'}</Typography>
        </Button>
    </span>
</Tooltip>
```

The property *mytestMultiLineContent* contains multiline data 
for e.g.

```html
"Reason is:  
I am good  
I am bad 
I am ugl"
```

Since the data is set to title property it will be encoded out. Is there a way to achieve multi line string data to be displayed on Tooltip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/

I found that the `title` props type is `Node`.

It means you can use `HTML` tags like this

```
<Tooltip disableFocusListener title={<span><p>first</p><p>second</p></span>}   >
    <span>
        <Button color={'primary'}   variant={'contained'}
            onClick={this.handleXYZ}
            disabled={!xyzStore.canSaveXYZ}
        >
            <Icon fontSize={'small'} >{'save'}</Icon>
            <Typography variant={'button'} >{'Save XYZ'}</Typography>
        </Button>
    </span>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: the problem is the tooltip will always be showing whether or not "first" or "second" property has value as title has a non zero length

Comment: @Lin you can convert your text to `Node` form

Comment: You are correct the title props supports rendering other components

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my final solution to this as might help.

```
<Tooltip title={
    xyzStore.disabledMessages.length
        ? (<React.Fragment>
            {xyzStore.disabledMessages.map((value, index) => {
                return (<Typography key={index} variant='caption' display='block'>{value}</Typography>)
            })}
        </React.Fragment>)
        : ''
            }  >
    <span>
        <Button> 
            <Typography>{'Save'}</Typography>
        </Button>
    </span>
</Tooltip>
```

The idea was to show multiple messages on the disabled button upon mouse over and thanks to "zynkn" for providing the clue.